# How can I use web scraping to import sale data from StockX into a Google Sheet?

Tags: javascript, url, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import the "last sale" data from StockX into my Google Sheet so that it can constantly update without me having to check it repeatedly. I've been trying to use the IMPORTXML function from Google, but I get an error. For example, when trying to get the "last sale" data for the Air Jordan 13 "Court Purple" (GS) in size 6.5Y, I get the error, `Could not fetch url: https://stockx.com/air-jordan-13-retro-court-purple-gs`. The function I am using is `=IMPORTXML("https://stockx.com/air-jordan-13-retro-court-purple-gs", "//*[@id='main-content']/div/section[1]/div[8]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/p[2]")`, and I can't seem to figure out why it's not working. The first parameter is the URL and the second parameter is the XPath that I copied directly from the Chrome Dev Tools window, which I opened using the "Inspect" function.

Comment: It seems the site is blocking access from Google server which giving 403 error.

Comment: @idfurw Ok, thanks. Do you know how I can circumvent this error? Perhaps by a different method than IMPORTXML altogether?